# Zend Framework 2 with Doctrine 2 custom validation and object structure

Tags: php, oop, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

What would be a proper class and object structure which would supports custom validations in **ZF2** and **Doctrine2**?

For example, I have a simple User Entity, and I wish to check if the email provided is unique. This validation requires access to the `EntityManager` so it can't be done from the Entity in its `getInputFilter` method.

What is a proper application structure to support that?

In my current workflow the User's name is validated in the controller, but this seems kind of wrong. The relevant objects and scripts are
    VIEW:       edituser.phtml
    CONTROLLER: UserController.php
                       - gets user post input and serves
                       - creates a validator, and checks if ($validator->isValid())
    ENTITY:     User.php
                       - performs other basic property validation, but cannot perform isUnique

If I need to create a custom validation class, which object would instantiate and use it? Do I absolutely need to have a separate User business model apart from the Entity, to have a healthy OOP structure ?

Comment: Use the object exists validator that ships with the DoctrineOrm module http://marco-pivetta.com/doctrine-orm-zf2-tutorial/#/32

Comment: Crisp, this was actually not my question, but thank you. I am currently using that same Validator, but I am instantiating and calling it from the controller. Since I don't think that is the best way to be using it, can you recommend from which class should I be using it ?

Comment: Ah, ok. I see I have mis-read. One thing I'm now unclear on though is `ENTITY: User.php - performs other basic property validation`. Are you saying your entity is responsible for its own validation? The form would normally take care of that, supplying the fields and, by way of implementing the `InputFilterAwareInterface`, supplying the filters and validators to apply to those fields. With that in mind, normally you would inject the entity manager as a dependency of your form and then use it with the object exists validator in your input filter spec.

Comment: Yes, my Entity implemented InputFilterAwareInterface and validation was performed by its inputFilter. I have modeled it like that because in a previous framework I've been using (Kohana), the validation is performed that way, at the Entity level.I have now followed your recommendation and used a Form class to do that. It is a better solution and an improvement, I must say. Thank you for your advice ! The only thing I'm not quite happy with is writing "too much" code: the Entity properties, the Form fields, and inputFilter elements all seem to refer to the same properties.